# D2L Basic LTI - How can I submit data other than grade data that users can see?

Tags: php, desire2learn, lti

I'm using Desire2Learn as my LMS and am also in the process of creating an external learning tool that users will then play. When they are finished, they will have their score (grade) submitted along with some other metrics.

I know that it's trivial to submit grade data back to the LMS, but is it possible to send data other than grade data back in a form that is visible to the user the next time he/she signs on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on what you mean by 'send data other than grade data ... that is visible'.

You could implement the LTI Tool Provider as a [Remote Plugin](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ui-ext/rplugins.html) in widget form that could go on a course home page. When a student visits the course home page, the widget auto-launches to the Tool Provider, and you can control the visual appearance you send back, based on whether the student has already played, whether they're seeing "the high score screen", etc, etc.

You can also [combine use of pure LTI in your Tool Provider and the Valence Learning Framework APIs](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ui-ext/rplugins.html#using-learning-framework-apis-with-remote-plugins) to help build a richer user experience. You might decide, for example, to record information for a student in their User Profile, or get richer access to the gradebook to provide more complex reporting for student performance than offered by pure LTI Outcome Service (in this case, your Tool Provider likely needs to be provisioned with an instructor or admin user account that will have access to the gradebook to make Valence calls, because the student user actually interacting with the Tool Provider UI won't have such access).

D2L's LTI implementation is conformant only with 1.x at this point, and supports only the basic Outcome Service (letting you send back a single, numeric grade).

Comment: Thanks for your answer on this. Based on my current understanding of how D2L manages LTI integration this seems like it might be plausible. If I understand correctly, if I insert the tool in a widget, I will be able to display any kind of relevant information to each user as long as the tool's access to the data is satisfied?

Comment: A widget remote plugin will basically get an iFrame in the LMS' rendered page, and your Tool Provider implementation can put pretty much what it likes inside that iFrame. As it's an iFrame it will have very limited access to the context surrounding it -- any information it needs "from the LMS" would need to come with the LTI launch itself, or using subsequent calls to the Valence Learning Framework APIs.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Viktor that makes sense. One last question, but would you happen to know if remote plugins are integrated as their own independent module? By this I mean are they something completely different than regular external learning tools in D2L? I haven't been able to find a thorough answer about this either anywhere on the net.

Comment: Nevermind about the remote plugin question I asked in my comment above. I actually just found my answer to that after I posting it.